# First 10 weeks of a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, week-number

Write a `SELECT` statement against the `Sales.Orders` and `Sales.OrderDetails` tables 
and retrieve all the distinct values for the **productid** column.

Filter the results to include only orders placed in the ***first 10 weeks of the year*** 2007.

I am having troubles with the filtering part.

What I've tried:

```
select * from Sales.Orders o 
join Sales.OrderDetails d 
on o.orderid=d.orderid 
group by o.productid 
having orderdate between '2017-01-01' and '2017-03-12';
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: select * 

from 

Sales.Orders o
join 
Sales.OrderDetails d
on o.orderid=d.orderid
group by o.productid
having  orderdate  between '2017-01-01' and '2017-03-12' ;

Comment: But let's say i don't know the dates, since i did a google search for the week 10 ending date.  Can i use any functions ?

Comment: @evelynepatras, Try my answer. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

The **DATEADD** function will give you the value of `10 week(70 days)`.

```
select * 
from Sales.Orders o 
join Sales.OrderDetails d on o.orderid=d.orderid 
WHERE orderdate >= '2017-01-01' and orderdate <= DATEADD(DAY,70,'2017-01-01')
```

Comment: But what is the first week of the year? Is it the year's first full week, or is it the week the year started on, even if it started on Wednsday? Also, a related question - does the 10th week of the year ends exactly 70 days after it started, or does it end on Sunday (or Saturday for Jewish people, or Friday for Muslim people)?

Comment: i have another solution:   WHERE DATEDIFF(week,'2007/01/01',O.orderdate) <=10;  i think both do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You want a `where` clause to filter the dates.  Then you want to select only the product ids:

```
select distint od.productid
from Sales.Orders o join
     Sales.OrderDetails od 
     on o.orderid = d.orderid 
where o.orderdate >= '2017-01-01' and
      o.orderdate < dateadd(week, 11, '2017-01-01');
```